# Add disabled product to quote & special pricing

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, price, quote

I'm busy creating an order programmatically, and want the process to add the product list to the order regardless of the product status.

It works fine, but when the product has a status of disabled (i.e status value is 2) then the price that is saved is `0.00`. (I see this in the `sales_flat_quote_item` table).

I've tried calling `Mage::helper('catalog/product')->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);` but that doesn't help either.

Here's the full code

```
foreach ($product_ids as $id){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $product->load($id);
            $product_info = array('qty'=>$product_qtys[$counter]);
            $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($product_info));
            $counter++;
        }
```

I've also tried using custom pricing, and that doesn't seem to affect the price on the quote at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I used was as follows:

```
 foreach ($product_ids as $id){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $product->load($id);
            $product_info = array('qty'=>$product_qtys[$counter]);
            $product->setStatus(1);//enabled, but don't save changes, works 100%
            $quote_item = $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($product_info));
            $quote_item->setCustomPrice($pricing[$counter]);
            $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($pricing[$counter]);
            $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            $counter++;
        }
$quote->save();
```